# deductions in a propositional calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hope you're all doing well. I have a question about deductions in logical systems. Say we have a *logic* in the language of propositional logic. We can think of this as the set of tautologies  of propositional logic, along with the inference rule *modus ponents*.

(See [*logic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) for a rigorous definition of a *logic*, under the section "generic description of a propositional calculus.")

If we know that $A$ and $B$ are well-formed-formulas that are both contained in this set, is it true that $A \wedge B$ is also in this set? Any hints as to how one would go about showing this?

Thank you!

Sincerely,

Vien

Comment: From the sound of it, what you mean by theory might be different from what others mean. Logicians say a *theory* is a set of sentences (and depending on the logician, they may also add that it has to be closed under logical consequence). If your theories are closed under logical consequence, then in general, yes, if $A$ and $B$ is in the theory, then so is $A \wedge B$. If theories are just plain ol' sets of sentences, then no, but the set of consequences of that theory does have this property.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry! I don't mean $\textit{theory}$, i mean a $\textit{logic}$ (some say $\textit{propositional calculus}$) as defined in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus.

Comment: So it's not possible(we're thinking of a logic now, not a theory) using the modus ponens rule of the logic? Thanks everyone for the help/answers by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *technically* feasible to devise a logic such that $A$ and $B$ are in the logic, but not $A \wedge B$. For instance, you could devise a logic which never makes use of $\wedge$ (it might only use $\rightarrow$, for instance). Such logics are interesting to study formally, but the lack of this "closure under conjunction" property is of course to be expected.

For the most part, logics with $\wedge$ will generally include enough machinery to prove $A \wedge B$ given that $A$ and $B$ are both provable (i.e. tautologies). In fact, one might question whether or not $\wedge$ *could even be conjunction* if it failed to have this closure property. Indeed, in many cases, the connective $\wedge$ has this property *by definition*. In Greg Restall's *An Introduction to Substructural Logics*, for instance, $\wedge$ is by definition a binary connective such that from $X \vdash A$ and $X \vdash B$, you can infer $X \vdash A \wedge B$ (so, in particular, if $A$ and $B$ are tautologies, then so is $A \wedge B$).

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This question was answered here *before* the term "**theory**" was replaced by "**logic**" in the original post.

---

Note that as it's used in logic, a [theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_%28mathematical_logic%29) is a set of sentences (wffs), and depending on what one's definition of a theory, there may be the added stipulation that this set of sentences (well-formed formulas) is *closed under logical consequence*.

So: If your theory is a set of sentences/wffs that is closed under logical consequence, then yes, if $A$ and $B$ are wffs in the theory, then so is $A\land B$. If the theory is just a set of wffs, then no. However, if $A, B$ belong to the set of *consequences* of such a theory, then so does $A \land B$.

Comment: Have a great night! :-) +1

Answer (score 1):

First off, what's your definition of a wff?

Second, if we know A and B are wffs in the set of all wffs of the logic, it is not necessarily the case that (A$\land$B) belongs to the set of wffs.  "$\land$" has to exist in the omega set for this to happen.  Sometimes "$\land$" doesn't exist in the omega set.  "(A$\land$B)" gets written to abbreviate wffs.  An example of this actually comes as example 1 on the Wikipedia page you've referenced, where (A$\land$B) abbreviates $\lnot$(A$\rightarrow$$\lnot$B).

Also, it consists of a simple matter to find logics where "$\land$ doesn't abbreviate anything.  Let's talk about a few of them by their axioms:

First, let's keep the alpha, omega, and zeta sets constant for the following logics.

Next, let's define the alpha set as all lower case letters of the Latin alphabet unsubscripted by Hindu-Arabic numerals or subscripted by Hindu-Arabic numerals.

Then, let's define the omega set as the binary operator C, and use Polish notation.  Thus our formation rules for wffs go:

1) All lower case letters subscripted by Hindu-Arabic numerals or unsubscripted by Hindu-Arabic numerals are wffs.

2) If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are wffs, then C$\alpha$$\beta$ is a wff.

3) Nothing else for the present context is a wff.

After that, let's define the zeta set as including the rule of detachment "from $\alpha$ and C$\alpha$$\beta$, we may infer $\beta$," and the rule of uniform substitution "if we have a thesis $\gamma$ which has $\delta$ as a variable, and if we substitute any wff $\zeta$ *uniformly* for $\delta$ in $\gamma$ (all instances of $\delta$ need to get substituted by $\zeta$), then the resulting wff $\gamma$'$\zeta$ is also a thesis".

Now, since those all will come as the same for the following, let's simply refer to logics by their axiom sets, with the added stipulation that all axioms are tautologies in two-valued logic.  One logic is {CpCqp}, another is {CCpqCCqrCpr}, another is {CCpCqrCCpqCpr}, another is {CpCCpqq}, another is {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr}, another is {CCqrCCpqCpq}, another is {CCpCqrCqCpr}, another is {CCCpqpp}, another is {CpCCpqq, CCqrCCpqCCrsCps}, another is {CCpCqrCCsqCpCsr}, another is {CCCCqrCprsCCpqs, CqCpq}, another is {CpCCqpp, Cpp, CCCpqrCCprr}, and so on.  Several of just the logics listed here have an infinity of theses which are not substitution instances of the axioms.  One could also talk about "the implicational calculus" here.

Added: The only truth functions for truth set {0, 1} you can obtain from just C can get represented by the following, since any combination of two of the following seven tables by C yields one of the following seven tables:

```
 a   b  Cab  Cba  Caa  CCabb  CCaba
 0   0  1    1    1    0      0            
 0   1  1    0    1    1      0            
 1   0  0    1    1    1      1           
 1   1  1    1    1    1      1
```

Consequently, there does not exist any way to represent conjunction in any of the logics I've talked about above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your help. It did turn out that the axioms of the logic I was working with was strong enough to prove that given $A$ and $B$ in the logic, that $A \wedge B$ was also in the logic. The step that I completely missed was that, given $p,q$ propositional variables, $p \rightarrow q \rightarrow (p \wedge q)$ (with the $\rightarrow$s grouped to the right by convention) is a tautology of sentential logic. Replacing $p$ by $A$ and $q$ by $B$ gives a tautology in my logic. Then by modus ponens(which is an inference rule of my logic), $A \wedge B$ is a formula of my logic. Again, thanks for all of your answers! They definitely helped me in my thinking.